# Norm of the maximum

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Consider the norm $||f||= max_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)|$ defined in the bectorial space $C[a,b]$

I have to what is the meaning (/interpretation) in $R$ of {$||f_n-f||$}$\to$ 0

Could you help me?

Comment: $\lVert f_n - f\rVert \leqslant \varepsilon$ means you have $\lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. To what type of convergence does that seem related?

Comment: Uniform convergence

Comment: Exactly. That is the norm of uniform convergence, and $\lVert f_n - f\rVert \to 0$ means that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$.